# Mongo DB Mongoose Query Assistance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm confused by something at the moment. I'm attempting to use a dynamic mongoose query based on the data submitted to a certain route (nodejs/expressjs). See below for code sample.

```
  reportingRouter.route('/filterData')

.post((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);


  function findFilteredResults(query) {
    // Performing a find on passdowns collection.
    // Criteria....
    // Find any passdown with a date that is greater than or equal to the startDate and less than or equal to the endDate.
    // Once found, if any, send back to client and render results in table rows.
    app.locals.passdowns.find(query, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      // If the array of objects/entries empty, no results were found. Send 404.
      else if (result.length === 0) {
        console.log(result);          
        res.status(404);
      }
      // If the array has 1 object or more, we've found results and need to send 200 okay and result to client.
      else if (result.length >= 1) {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).send(result);
      }
    });
  }

  var mongooseQuery;

  if (req.body.shift !== '') {
    console.log('shift is not blank');
    findFilteredResults(`{ date_time: { $gte: new Date(req.body.startDate), $lte: new Date(req.body.endDate) }, shift: req.body.shift }`);      
  }
  else if (req.body.shift === '') {
    console.log('shift is blank');
    findFilteredResults(`{ date_time: { $gte: new Date(req.body.startDate), $lte: new Date(req.body.endDate) } }`);           
  }

});
```

I've placed my mongoose find logic inside of a function. This is to be called for the different cases based on data sent to server. Is it possible to do such a thing where I pass the mongoose query into function as parameter? Everything I've tried so far has failed for me.

The query either runs as if it's searching for "*" or it doesn't find anything because it thinks the following is a string.

```
{ date_time: { $gte: new Date(req.body.startDate), $lte: new Date(req.body.endDate) } }
```

Comment: It thinks that's a string because you're passing it as a string :). Remove the backticks that surround it in your code so that it's passed as an object instead.

Comment: Guess I was over-thinking things here. Thanks for the assistance @JohnnyHK. I just re-tested things and it's working as expected.